# System-wide shortcut to switch to a specific tab in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-el-capitan

I would like to set up system-wide shortcuts (i.e. that I can use from anywhere) to switch to the running instance of different websites. For instance, `Shift-Command-s` to mean "Look for a running instance of Firefox and switch to the tab containing Stackoverflow". Is something like that possible on OSX?

I would also like the ability to switch to other apps (other than web browsers) with a keyboard shortcut. How can I go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but what I can tell, in Firefox, in Windows, you can switch between tabs by pressing Control and numbers, what I use and what are especially useful when having pinned tabs and switching between them, because usually you don't have many tabs pinned. So, basically, Ctrl+1 would mean the first tab, Ctrl+2 the second tab and so on up until the eighths tab, because the number 9 stands for the last tab(!) opened.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055148/select-a-tab-in-firefox-from-command-line